How to configure basic authentification with htpasswd on moongoose swupdate webserver?
I put in this configuration for my SWUPDATE webserver:
SWUPDATE_WEBSERVER_ARGS=" -r /srv/swupdate/mongoose-webapp -p 8081 --auth-domain 'SWUpdate' --global-auth-file /home/swupdate-cred/.htpasswd "
I now get the authentication popup when I try to access port 8081 .
I tried putting the username and password I created with this command here:

      htpasswd -c /home/swupdate-cred/.htpasswd ckm

But it never lets me log in, with the user and pw I configured...
i don't understand, should i create users in a certain way? with the specified domain? help
I use SWUpdate v2023.05.0

I have resolved the issue:
You need to create the password by specifying the realm as follows:
htdigest -c .htpasswd realmyouwanttoset username_setted 
Enter password: pwfantasy 
Retype password: pwfantasy 

Then, you can set the arguments as shown below:
SWUPDATE_WEBSERVER_ARGS=" -r /srv/swupdate/mongoose-webapp -p 8081 --auth-domain realmyouwanttoset --global-auth-file /whereyourfileis/.htpasswd " 

Basic authentication configured successfully. 
